# Divide one dataframe by another disconsidering one column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two data frames:

```
df1:
      Produtos       Jan       Feb       Mar       Apr       May       Jun  \
0          100   15884.0    8194.0   41070.0    8294.0   17308.0   18146.0   
1        10057       0.0       0.0       0.0   24900.0       0.0       0.0   
2        10058       0.0       0.0       0.0   30900.0       0.0       0.0   
3        10236   11638.0    8450.0    1690.0    3380.0   10140.0    1690.0   
4        10267       0.0       0.0       0.0   11490.0       0.0       0.0   
5        10273   18157.0   32434.0    4900.0       0.0   10588.0   15094.0 


df2:
      Produtos     Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     May     Jun     Jul     Aug
0          100   600.0   200.0  1100.0   300.0   500.0  1600.0     0.0     0.0
1        10057     0.0     0.0     0.0   100.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
2        10058     0.0     0.0     0.0   100.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
3        10236   700.0   500.0   100.0   200.0   600.0   100.0   200.0   100.0
4        10267     0.0     0.0     0.0   100.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
5        10273   400.0   700.0   100.0     0.0   200.0   300.0   300.0   300.0
```

I am trying to divide one dataframe by another, in order to create a new one. However, I don`t know how to make this division without considering the first column 'Produtos'.

Doing this:

```
v = df1.values / df2.values
```

I get the first column divided as well.

Comment: I think the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49412694/divide-two-pandas-dataframes-and-keep-non-numeric-columns) should be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know your dataframe shape and `Produtos` series are aligned, you can use NumPy as so:

```
df1.iloc[:, 1:] /= df2.iloc[:, 1:].values

print(df1)

   Produtos        Jan        Feb        Mar         Apr     May        Jun
0       100  26.473333  40.970000  37.336364   27.646667  34.616  11.341250
1     10057        NaN        NaN        NaN  249.000000     NaN        NaN
2     10058        NaN        NaN        NaN  309.000000     NaN        NaN
3     10236  16.625714  16.900000  16.900000   16.900000  16.900  16.900000
4     10267        NaN        NaN        NaN  114.900000     NaN        NaN
5     10273  45.392500  46.334286  49.000000         NaN  52.940  50.313333
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have division by 0 problems, leading to `NaN` values, but assuming that the `Produtos` columns are equal (as they are in your question), you can set that column to the index, then use `.div`:

```
df1.set_index('Produtos').div(df2.set_index('Produtos'))

                 Apr  Aug        Feb        Jan  Jul        Jun        Mar  \
Produtos                                                                     
100        27.646667  NaN  40.970000  26.473333  NaN  11.341250  37.336364   
10057     249.000000  NaN        NaN        NaN  NaN        NaN        NaN   
10058     309.000000  NaN        NaN        NaN  NaN        NaN        NaN   
10236      16.900000  NaN  16.900000  16.625714  NaN  16.900000  16.900000   
10267     114.900000  NaN        NaN        NaN  NaN        NaN        NaN   
10273            NaN  NaN  46.334286  45.392500  NaN  50.313333  49.000000   

             May  
Produtos          
100       34.616  
10057        NaN  
10058        NaN  
10236     16.900  
10267        NaN  
10273     52.940
```

If they're not always equal, and you just want to divide the corresponding index numbers, use `drop('Produtos',1)`:

```
>>> df1.drop('Produtos',1).div(df2.drop('Produtos',1))
          Apr  Aug        Feb        Jan  Jul        Jun        Mar     May
0   27.646667  NaN  40.970000  26.473333  NaN  11.341250  37.336364  34.616
1  249.000000  NaN        NaN        NaN  NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN
2  309.000000  NaN        NaN        NaN  NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN
3   16.900000  NaN  16.900000  16.625714  NaN  16.900000  16.900000  16.900
4  114.900000  NaN        NaN        NaN  NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN
5         NaN  NaN  46.334286  45.392500  NaN  50.313333  49.000000  52.940
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iloc` to ignore the first column in each dataframe and divide the result.

```
>>> df1.iloc[:, 1:].div(df2.iloc[:, 1:])[df1.columns[1:]]

         Jan        Feb        Mar         Apr     May        Jun
0  26.473333  40.970000  37.336364   27.646667  34.616  11.341250
1        NaN        NaN        NaN  249.000000     NaN        NaN
2        NaN        NaN        NaN  309.000000     NaN        NaN
3  16.625714  16.900000  16.900000   16.900000  16.900  16.900000
4        NaN        NaN        NaN  114.900000     NaN        NaN
5  45.392500  46.334286  49.000000         NaN  52.940  50.313333
```

Comment: I don't see any expected output, so I'm not sure this assumption is correct.  If so, it is easy to include.

Comment: You're right, I mistakenly thought the second DataFrame was the desired output- still I think it makes sense to include the first column.