# After reinstalling Anaconda I can't use numpy or install a requirements.txt

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, requirements.txt

I had issues while running  some notebooks because things would slow down too much. I had to restart the kernel every time to get things running normally. I decided to reinstall anaconda all over, but now things don't work.

A numpy line that used to be able to run now doesn't:
`np.divide(b, a, where=a.dtypes.ne(object)).combine_first(a)`. This is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49412694/divide-two-pandas-dataframes-and-keep-non-numeric-columns/49412743) post. The error is the following: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'`. But again, it used to work.

I thought the problem would be fixed when considering the version of numpy and python, by loading a requirements.txt file that was available (and worked before). But now this does not work either. I get the following error: `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\ci\\argon2-cffi_1596828585465\\work'`. I found that the problem had to do with the path, but I could not fix it.

I also tried manually downgrading both python and numpy, but nothing.

Any idea of what could be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the first error statement:

**TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'**

it appears that was due to the data type (string in your case) in the data computation. Similar to this error: [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235703/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-str)

Perhaps, you can reinstall the numpy module in your Conda terminal, if you found the Numpy is not properly installed. [Installing Conda package](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/install-packages/)

Comment: I tried reinstalling numpy several times, but it did not seem to work. At the end, only installing an old version of Anaconda from [here](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/) fixed it

Comment: Good to hear that you resolve the issue after reinstalling to older version of Anaconda. I also found a link discussing similar issue as yours: [link](http://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/19306). Probably it would be helpful to you.